# Overlay div over screen but background color avoid area of page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a project where I want an ability to overlay a div over the top of an entire page but the background colour should avoid an area of the screen by a jquery selector.

Its a tricky thing to know how to Google it and unfortunately not had any success in doing what I want or a library that does what I want.

Below is a screenshot to show what it is I am trying to do.

[image: Exaple screenshot]

For example, I'm looking at doing something like the following:

The idea is to provide a sort of demo/tutorial so it can highlight certain areas and provide some text near by to explain a function or a setting etc.

For example, I might have something like the below:

```
demoLib.show("#btnHighlightMyButton", "Show this text near by");
```

Hopefully how I'vve explained what I am trying to do so it makes sense but if not let me.

So basically, the question is how can I set a background gradient but the background avoid the area of the selector as shown in the screenshot

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @j08691 updated to make it more clear

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: At the moment nothing as I've no idea where to start or found anything remotely related to what I want on Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `z-index`.

**Example:**

```js
focus("#button2");

function focus(elem){

  $(elem).css({"z-index":"100"});
  
  $(elem).click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("id"))
  })

  let buttonW = $(elem).css("width");
  let buttonH = $(elem).css("height");

  let offset = $(elem).offset();

  let buttonpos = [offset["top"],offset["left"]];

  $('.overlay #focusspot').css(
    {
      "width":parseInt(buttonW)+30+"px",
      //+30 will act like a padding!
      "height":parseInt(buttonH)+30+"px",
      "border-radius":"50%",
      "background":"white",
      "position":"absolute",
      "top":`${buttonpos[0]-15}px`,
      //-15 is half the 30px we added above (to center perfectly)!
      "left":`${buttonpos[1]-15}px`
    }
   );
  
}
```

```css
body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
div.container{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
button{
  margin: 0px 10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
div.overlay{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.54);
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <button id="button1">Button one</button>
  <button id="button2">Button two</button>
  <button id="button3">Button three</button>

</div>

<div class="overlay">
  <div id="focusspot"></div>
</div>
```

I hope this help.

Comment: What if he wants to show the focused item in circle?

Comment: @MuhammadOsama the answer is updated, Check it out!

Comment: That's awesome, that's what I was after - I think I over complicated the idea in my head. This is a nice simple solution :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe use a z-index in css to make a image cover the whole page, then make it transparent with rgba, make your a like 75% maybe - for the shadowed cover effect.

as for the white opening, might want to check out coordinates.

canvas is also a technology you might use.

best of luck